# You must be root to use this library on linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyautogui

Пытаюсь запустить следующий фрагмент:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
            break
        coordinate_whell = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
            image='blue.jpg',
        )
        print(coordinate_whell)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Ожидаю, что код найдёт картинку на экране и выдаст её координаты, но ловлю следующее:

`You must be root to use this library on linux.`

Почитал о том, что это связано с установкой `keyboard` без прав суперпользователя. Переустановил, используя

`sudo pip3 install keyboard`

Но ситуацию это не поправило. Код всё ещё не запускается. Подскажите, в чём проблема?

Comment: В том, что нужно не устанавливать с правами рута, а запускать с правами рута

Comment: @andreymal а можно ли что-то сделать, чтобы работало с обычным запуском?

Comment: Если бы было можно, то библиотека keyboard не стала бы требовать от вас права рута

Comment: А вообще у вас подход скорее всего неправильный: библиотека keyboard отслеживает физические устройства (поэтому и требует рута), а наличие pyautogui намекает, что вам на самом деле нужно отслеживать события в графическом интерфейсе. Попробуйте какой-нибудь pynput, он использует xorg и не требует рута

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 1):

Обновите модуль keyboard. В новом такая ошибка отсутствует.

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard.git
```

Но нужно добавить пользотателя в группу `input` и перезагрузиться

```
sudo gpasswd -a user input
```

Сырые устройства ввода лежат в папке `/dev/input/` с правами `crw-rw----  root input`

Comment: Однако [вот этот issue](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/312) почему-то до сих пор висит открытым

Comment: @andreymal ещё висит открытым #420 но код, вызывающий это исключение уже отсутствует

Comment: добавил то что нужно обновить